# Sort Array in lexicographical order

Tags: java, sorting, substring

I do not know why my code does not work. I am trying to sort in lexicographical order an array of substrings of the input string. and then get the smallest and largest element.
example:

> **Input**: 
>   s= fares & k=2  
>   **array of substrings will be** = {fa,ar,re,es}
>    **Output**: 
>   ar
>   re

with `k` the size of substring.

I tried  "helloworld" with substring of 3 elements (k=3) and did not work.

```
public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
    String smallest = "";
    String largest = "";
    String[] str=new String[s.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<s.length()-k;i++){
        String holder=s.substring(i,i+k);
        str[i]=holder;
    }
    Arrays.sort(str); 

    smallest=str[0];
    largest=str[s.length()-1];


    return smallest + "\n" + largest;
}
```

Comment: What's your example input and output?

Comment: Example of how you call this method please. and what is `k`?

Comment: @Fares Jellali I have added the explanation why ur code dont work and a single loop to solve ur problem

Comment: I have updated it I thought the size has to be split in K , But now I got the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Hades it was who downvoted it because it was wrong, now it is turned to upvote

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the length of the `str` 
the value of `str`for the example i.e. s=fares and k = 2 is

```
[fa, ar, re, null, null]
```

hence Arrays.sort throwing exception 
Also u can find the max and minimum in same loop, there is no separate need for sorting 
I have made a code for the same

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getSmallestAndLargest("fares",2));
}

public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
    String substring = s.substring(0, k);
    String smallest = substring;
    String largest = "";
    while(s.length()>=k) {
        String temp  = s.substring(0, k);
        System.out.println(temp);
        smallest = smallest.compareTo(temp)<0?smallest:temp;
        largest = largest.compareTo(temp)>0?largest:temp;
        s= s.substring(1,s.length());
    }
    System.out.println("***************** Result");
    return smallest+"\n"+largest;
}
```

output

```
fa
ar
re
es
***************** Result
ar
re
```

with `K = 3`

```
far
are
res
***************** Result
are
res
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the size of the array of substrings which you initialize it to the length of the String (here `String[] str=new String[s.length()];`) which is wrong. that's why you will get Null Exception.

for example, for s=fares and k = 2 your array will be of size 5 and you will get as follow

```
[fa, ar, re, null, null]
```

the actual size of the array is `s.length() - k -1` , so you only have to change this value, and keep all your code

```
public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
    String smallest = "";
    String largest = "";
    int length = s.length() - k +1;
    String[] str=new String[length];

    for(int i=0;i<=s.length() -k;i++){
        String holder=s.substring(i,i+k);
        str[i]=holder;
    }
    Arrays.sort(str); 

    smallest=str[0];
    largest=str[length-1];


    return smallest + "\n" + largest;
}
```

Comment: wth s = fares and k = 2 the debugg value will be [fa, ar, re, null, null] , please check.

Comment: @FaresJellali you're welcome :)) please accept my answer if it helped you, by clicking on the check button (on the left of the answer)